# Displaying form data on the calendar in ui-calendar and saving it in fireabase

Tags: angularjs, calendar, firebase, angularfire

I am using UI-Calendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and i want the form filled to be dispalyed on the respective calendar entries and saved in firebase database.How do i do that? At the moment form data is not getting dislayed on the calendar ?

appointment-maker.js file

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name appointment1App.controller:CalendarCtrl
 * @description
 * # CalendarCtrl
 * Controller of the appointment1App
 */
angular.module('Appointment1app')
    .controller('CalendarCtrl', function ($scope) {

        function dayClick() {
            $scope.templates.myTemplate = "views/appointment-maker.html";
        }

        function eventDrop() {

        }

        function alertOnResize() {

        }

        $scope.eventSources = [];
        $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar: {
                height: 450,
                editable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'today prev,next'
                },
                dayClick: dayClick,
                eventDrop: eventDrop,
                eventResize: alertOnResize
            }
        };
    });
```

calendar.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name appointment1App.controller:CalendarCtrl
 * @description
 * # CalendarCtrl
 * Controller of the appointment1App
 */
angular.module('Appointment1app')
    .controller('CalendarCtrl', function ($scope) {


        function dayClick() {
            $scope.templates.myTemplate = "views/appointment-maker.html";
        }

        function eventDrop() {

        }

        function alertOnResize() {

        }


        $scope.eventSources = [];
        $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar: {
                height: 450,
                editable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'today prev,next'
                },
                dayClick: dayClick,
                eventDrop: eventDrop,
                eventResize: alertOnResize



            }
        };
    });
```

HTML

```
<form ng-controller="AppointmentMakerCtrl"
      ng-submit="onSubmitAppointment()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input class="form-control"
               ng-model="newAppointment.name">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input class="form-control"
               ng-model="newAppointment.email">
        <label>Notes</label>
        <input class="form-control"
               ng-model="newAppointment.notes">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
    ng-click="onCreateAppointment()">Create Appointment</button>

    <!-- <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="message in messages">{{message.value}}</li>
    </ul> -->
</form>
```

config.js file

```
  .constant('FBURL', 'http://dazzling-fire-6922.firebaseio.com');
```

Complete code here https://github.com/matif84/class-project-angularjs

Comment: Are you using `$firebase` or `Firebase` anywhere in your code? They're not present in the code snippet above, which would go a long way towards explaining why no data is being bound between your form controls and Firebase.

Comment: I did that in config.js file.The complete code is here https://github.com/matif84/class-project-angularjs

Comment: Please update your question to include a **minimal self-contained reproduction** of your problem. But from what I see in https://github.com/matif84/class-project-angularjs/blob/master/app/scripts/angularfire/config.js, there is nothing binding a AngularFire sync object to the scope. That code would also normally be in your `CalendarCtrl`, similar to how you do it in `AppointmentMakerCtrl` for the `messages` array.

Comment: I added content to make it self contained and added github url too .How do i go around binding AngularFire object to the scope?

Comment: That config fragment just set up a Firebase URL. It's up to your own code to create a `Firebase` ref on that and then a `$firebase` sync object, that you cast to `$asObject()`. Once you have that you can bind it to your Angular model. All these steps are explained in the AngularFire QuickStart: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html